# jqueryui how to set a limit to the draggable object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vm7vbLkm/1/

So far i have this, what i want to do is that instead of dragging the elements all the way out, i want to retrain it so that the max the most left element can only be like 30px left at most, and same to the right, if u drag on both side the first/last element can only be 30px max away from the container.

Any idea how i can do it?

```
$('.drag').draggable({ axis: "x" });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "#draggable5" ).draggable({ containment: "parent" });
```

Have a look [jqueryui.com/draggable/#constrain-movement](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#constrain-movement)